# How to load a random favicon every load React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to randomly load a new favicon every time the page is reloaded in React? I want to have a list of icons and have one randomly chosen every time the page loads.

In the `manifest.json`, the favicon loading looks like this:

```
"icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
```

Is there any reasonable way to randomly pick an icon from a set of icons?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array of icons and use JavaScript’s **Math.random()** function to randomly select an icon from the array. Refer here:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const icons = [
  'favicon1.ico',
  'favicon2.ico',
  'favicon3.ico',
  // add more icons here
];

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const randomIcon = icons[Math.floor(Math.random() * icons.length)];
    const link = document.querySelector("link[rel~='icon']");
    link.href = randomIcon;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* your app content */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the above example, the **useEffect** hook is to run some code when the component mounts. We’re selecting a random icon from the icons array using **Math.random()** and updating the favicon by changing the href attribute of the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this

> Is there any reasonable way to randomly pick an icon from a set of icons?

Just use `Math.random` to get random index and pick an item from your icons array

```
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * icons.length);
const randomIcon = icons[randomIndex]
```